# Elasticsearch delete across all indexes and types

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a Java application that is using the elasticsearch jar to interface with an elasticsearch client.

What I would like to do is delete something from Elastricsearch when I only know the ID.  So, I do not know the index OR type.  How can I do this?

I would think doing `...prepareDelete("_all","_all",<id>)` or `...prepareDelete("*","*",<id>)` would work, but neither are supported in Elasticsearch.

The only way I can think of doing this is to iterate over all indexes and types and delete each one with that ID, but that sounds a little inefficient if Elasticsearch already provides this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ES 1.7 one can still do:

```
DELETE /_all/_query?q=_id:123
```

as per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html, but in 2.0 it will be removed.

Comment: I am using the 2.0 beta and was still able to do this.  Is this going to be removed when 2.0 is officially released?

Comment: It will probably be removed, yes, and built as a plugin instead. Take a look at the list of removed features here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/_removed_features.html#_delete_by_query_is_now_a_plugin